# how disable text box from two give text box?

Tags: vb.net

I have 2 text box in one vb form. if txtMaterial was fill i want to disable the txtPackage and vice versa. I use the code below, but it didn't work. could someone fixed it. 
Really appreciate it. tq.

```
Private Sub txtMaterial_TextChange(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles txtMaterial.TextChanged
    txtMaterial.Enabled = True
    txtPackage.Enabled = False

End Sub

Private Sub txtPackage_TextChange(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles txtPackage.TextChanged

    txtPackage.Enabled = True
    txtMaterial.Enabled = False

End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

Make both TextBoxes fire the same handler, then simply set the Enabled() state of each one based on whether the other TextBox has something in it:

```
Private Sub txtChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles txtMaterial.TextChanged, txtPackage.TextChanged
    txtMaterial.Enabled = (txtPackage.TextLength = 0)
    txtPackage.Enabled = (txtMaterial.TextLength = 0)
End Sub
```

*Note the ending of the first line has both controls listed using `Handles txtMaterial.TextChanged, txtPackage.TextChanged` at the end.

Comment: It works perfectly for me; but I know what **I** was expecting.  Can give more details about how it "didn't work" for **you**?...

Comment: i want something like this, >> http://www.google.com.my/imgres?hl=en&biw=1600&bih=799&tbm=isch&tbnid=SNr1zLuM77_oJM:&imgrefurl=http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9952/ComboBox-with-read-only-behavior&docid=LKR5Ftbkgk0AGM&imgurl=http://www.codeproject.com/KB/combobox/ReadOnlyComboBoxByClaudio/ReadOnlyComboBox1.gif&w=248&h=144&ei=R5PTUcPLIeOoiAeEsIHIDw&zoom=1&ved=1t:3588,r:0,s:0,i:80&iact=rc&page=1&tbnh=115&tbnw=198&start=0&ndsp=18&tx=109&ty=42

Comment: Ok...great.  How is my code not working for you?  The image simply shows a TextBox in various states and I already stated that my example worked for me.  I need to know how it isn't working for you so I can either fix it or help you implement the solution for your specific case.

Comment: i want to make it disable as the second one. but in my case if i fill the txtMaterial the txtPackage also can be fill with text at the same time.

Comment: "... but in my case if i fill the txtMaterial the txtPackage also can be fill with text at the same time"  What?...that makes no sense with what you originally stated.  If you want to be able to fill in BOTH then why are you disabling them at all?  Confused.

Comment: "but in my case if i fill the txtMaterial the txtPackage also can be fill with text at the same time">> this is the problem and i want to solve them. i want to disable one of the text if the other is fill. and the problem still keep going although i use your code.

Comment: Did you make sure that BOTH of your TextBoxes TextChanged() events are being handled by that same method I posted?  **Also, make sure that you have disabled your old TextChanged() handlers as they could be undoing the code from the new handler.**

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub txtMaterial_TextChange(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles txtMaterial.TextChanged
    If txtMaterial.Text <> "" Then
        txtPackage.Enabled =False
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

based on the comment that you added

> Blockquote i want to make it disable as the second one. but in my case if i fill the txtMaterial the txtPackage also can be fill with text at the same time.

the solution to your problem must be this:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    txtPackage.Enabled = False
End Sub


Private Sub txtMaterial_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles txtMaterial.TextChanged
    If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtMaterial.Text) Then
        txtPackage.Enabled = True
    Else
        txtPackage.Enabled = False
    End If
End Sub
```